# Rails show everything inside table controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, rails-activerecord

I have a table. Simple question, How do I access all the rows?

I know you wouyld normally do this in the controller normally as

```
@event = Event.find(params[:id])
```

How would I look into making this show all the rows rather than relying on an ID.

I was thinking it may be just as simple as

```
@event = Event
```

But I thought i was best double checking here.

Comment: The level of ignorance of Rails displayed here is stunning and depressing.  StackOverflow is full of stupid questions like this that shouldn't even need to be asked if the poster had read ANYTHING at all about Rails before.  StackOverflow is not supposed to be a replacement for studying a subject.  Do some work yourself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `all` method:

```
@event = Event.all
```